# Why isn't this powershell sort working? (PhysicalDisk objects)

Tags: powershell

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-PhysicalDisk | Sort-Object Number

Number FriendlyName           SerialNumber MediaType   CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage            Size
------ ------------           ------------ ---------   ------- ----------------- ------------ -----            ----
3      Seagate Backup+  Desk  NA7E5JCS     Unspecified False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select   2.73 TB
0      Crucial_CT500MX200SSD1 162112CAE0AE SSD         False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 465.76 GB
2      Seagate Expansion Desk NA4K7L4K     Unspecified False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select   3.64 TB


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $psversionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.610
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.610
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: Same resullt from `Get-PhysicalDisk | Sort-Object -property Number`

Comment: FYI... There is also `Get-PhysicalDiskStorageNodeView` so `(Get-PhysicalDiskStorageNodeView).DiskNumber`

Answer (score 3):

> Why isn't this PowerShell sort working?
>
> `Get-PhysicalDisk | Sort-Object Number`

It appears like your syntax isn't correct.

```
Get-PhysicalDisk | Sort-Object -Property DeviceID -Descending
Get-PhysicalDisk | Sort-Object -Property DeviceID
```

Outputs:

```
Number FriendlyName            SerialNumber         MediaType CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage            Size
    ------ ------------            ------------         --------- ------- ----------------- ------------ -----            ----
    5      MSFT XVDD                                    SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select  29.38 GB
    4      MSFT XVDD                                    SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 109.91 GB
    3      MSFT XVDD                                    SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select  11.34 GB
    2      ST10000NM0086                                HDD       True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select    9.1 TB
    1      Samsung SSD 860 EVO 2TB                      SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select   1.82 TB
    0      Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB                      SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 953.87 GB

Number FriendlyName            SerialNumber         MediaType CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage            Size
    ------ ------------            ------------         --------- ------- ----------------- ------------ -----            ----
    0      Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB                      SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 953.87 GB
    1      Samsung SSD 860 EVO 2TB                      SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select   1.82 TB
    2      ST10000NM0086                                HDD       True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select    9.1 TB
    3      MSFT XVDD                                    SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select  11.34 GB
    4      MSFT XVDD                                    SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 109.91 GB
    5      MSFT XVDD                                    SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select  29.38 GB
```

Source: [Example 1: Sort the current directory by name](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-5.1)

[Get-PhysicalDisk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-physicaldisk?view=win10-ps) does not actually return a property named `Number` as evident by the following command:

```
 Get-PhysicalDisk | Select-Object Number, FriendlyName, Size

Number FriendlyName                      Size
------ ------------                      ----
       MSFT XVDD                  12179415040
       MSFT XVDD                 118010777600
       MSFT XVDD                  31548567552
       Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB  1024209543168
       ST10000NM0086            10000831348736
       Samsung SSD 860 EVO 2TB  2000398934016
```

While the following command returns the correct output:

```
Get-PhysicalDisk | Select-Object DeviceID, FriendlyName,Size

DeviceID FriendlyName                      Size
-------- ------------                      ----
3        MSFT XVDD                  12179415040
4        MSFT XVDD                 118010777600
5        MSFT XVDD                  31548567552
0        Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1TB  1024209543168
2        ST10000NM0086           10000831348736
1        Samsung SSD 860 EVO 2TB  2000398934016
```

Comment: No, that does not work, at least not in PowerShell 5.1.   Did you test it under a different version?  See my explanation/answer.

Comment: @Burt_Harris - **It's ignoring the attempt to sort on the property Number since it does not exist.**  This is proven by the fact if you attempt to do a descending, the output will be identical, to that of the ascending sort.

Comment: I was working on the answer before you submitted it. It's common for multiple users to come to the same conclusion in a short timeframe. As for it not working, I tested it against PowerShell 5.1, which is the same version you are using. Those are actual outputs.

Answer (score 3):

***Always, always use Get-Member to be sure you are getting the raw attributes*** vs what is displayed on the screen, which we all know is often manipulated.

```
(Get-PhysicalDisk)[0] | 
Get-Member
# Results
<#
   TypeName: Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#root/microsoft/windows/storage/MSFT_PhysicalDisk

Name                             MemberType     Definition                                                                                                                        
----                             ----------     ----------                                                                                                                        
...                                                                                                                
AdapterSerialNumber              Property       string AdapterSerialNumber {get;}                                                                                                 
AllocatedSize                    Property       uint64 AllocatedSize {get;}                                                                                                       
CanPool                          Property       bool CanPool {get;}                                                                                                               
Description                      Property       string Description {get;}                                                                                                         
DeviceId                         Property       string DeviceId {get;}                                                                                                            
EnclosureNumber                  Property       uint16 EnclosureNumber {get;}                                                                                                     
FirmwareVersion                  Property       string FirmwareVersion {get;}                                                                                                     
FriendlyName                     Property       string FriendlyName {get;}                                                                                                        
IsIndicationEnabled              Property       bool IsIndicationEnabled {get;}                                                                                                   
IsPartial                        Property       bool IsPartial {get;}                                                                                                             
LogicalSectorSize                Property       uint64 LogicalSectorSize {get;}                                                                                                   
Manufacturer                     Property       string Manufacturer {get;}                                                                                                        
Model                            Property       string Model {get;}                                                                                                               
ObjectId                         Property       string ObjectId {get;}                                                                                                            
OperationalDetails               Property       string[] OperationalDetails {get;}                                                                                                
OtherCannotPoolReasonDescription Property       string OtherCannotPoolReasonDescription {get;}                                                                                    
PartNumber                       Property       string PartNumber {get;}                                                                                                          
PassThroughClass                 Property       string PassThroughClass {get;}                                                                                                    
PassThroughIds                   Property       string PassThroughIds {get;}                                                                                                      
PassThroughNamespace             Property       string PassThroughNamespace {get;}                                                                                                
PassThroughServer                Property       string PassThroughServer {get;}                                                                                                   
PhysicalLocation                 Property       string PhysicalLocation {get;}                                                                                                    
PhysicalSectorSize               Property       uint64 PhysicalSectorSize {get;}                                                                                                  
PSComputerName                   Property       string PSComputerName {get;}                                                                                                      
SerialNumber                     Property       string SerialNumber {get;}                                                                                                        
Size                             Property       uint64 Size {get;}                                                                                                                
SlotNumber                       Property       uint16 SlotNumber {get;}                                                                                                          
SoftwareVersion                  Property       string SoftwareVersion {get;}                                                                                                     
StoragePoolUniqueId              Property       string StoragePoolUniqueId {get;}                                                                                                 
UniqueId                         Property       string UniqueId {get;}                                                                                                            
...
#>
```

***Obviously, 'Number' is a string rewrite of DeviceId.***

Answer (score 2):

Despite appearances, the objects returned by the Get-PhysicalDisk cmdlet don't have a "Number" property.   This column heading seems to be put onto a property known as DeviceID.   Furthermore, this ID is a string, so it needs to be cast to a number to sort properly.

So this should work, but I' not on a multi-disk machine to verify it:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>  Get-PhysicalDisk | Sort-Object {[int]$_.DeviceID}

Number FriendlyName           SerialNumber MediaType   CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage            Size
------ ------------           ------------ ---------   ------- ----------------- ------------ -----            ----
0      Crucial_CT500MX200SSD1 162112CAE0AE SSD         False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 465.76 GB
2      Seagate Expansion Desk NA4K7L4K     Unspecified False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select   3.64 TB
3      Seagate Backup+  Desk  NA7E5JCS     Unspecified False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select   2.73 TB
```

Thanks to @Jazimov for catching an earlier problem with my solution, which was data-dependent.   Now that I understand it, the string vs number sort makes sense.   It's not exactly a bug, but it's very counter-intuitive.

Comment: It's not a bug, the documentation simply isn't accurate for [`Get-PhysicalDisk`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-physicaldisk?view=win10-ps), PowerShell 7.1 behaves the sameway

Comment: Close, but not quite: This will sort disk Number values as 0, 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, etc., so it's not a numeric sort.

Comment: Interesting catch @Jazimov.

Comment: You are right, but there is a fix.   I'll update my answer, but thank you for catching this.

Comment: Thanks @Burt_Harris, but the above does not work, it produces an "Unexpected token 'DeviceID' in expression or statement" error on my system.

Comment: After doing some additional research, this worked for me: Get-PhysicalDisk | Sort-Object {[int]$_.DeviceID}

Comment: @Jazimov, that's good; why don't you make it an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: It's my gift to you if you want to revise your answer. :)